# Listen for next 5 key presses after hotkey is pressed

Tags: c#, keycode

I'm quite new to c# and I'm trying to create a small system tray app that pastes something in the active window (sends a CTRL+V command) based on a short text and hotkey that are written in the window.

Ex. If you type |hl in Notepad, the app will paste Hello in the active window.

So far I got the app to stat in system try using NotifyIcon, based on the example found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290013/Formless-System-Tray-Application), and was able to setup a keyboard hook to listen for key down events.

What I need now is this:

```
if(e.KeyCode.ToString() == "OemPipe") //if hotkey is pressed
{
    //listen for the next 5 KeyCode
    if(//next 5 KeyCode are A, B, C, D and E)
    {
         //do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        //ignore and listen for hotkey again
    }
}
```

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to find how this is done for a few days now, but I can't even find something to get me started.

Any ideeas would be greatly appreciated and if you have a code sample as well that would be even better.

Comment: Is this Web Forms or MVC or Windows Forms or WPF, or Silverlight or something else?

Comment: Post the full code of the key down events

Comment: Should have mentioned that, it's a Windows Forms app.

Comment: @Aruna for the hook, I used  this code [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to lend a hand.

I'm assuming you're receiving the Keycode by a `KeyEventArgs` object, if you scroll through its properties you will notice two interesting ones:

```
KeyEventArgs.Modifiers
KeyEventArgs.Shift
```

With those you will know if a key was pressed while holding CTRL, ALT or SHIFT, then in your code you can add into an array which keys were consecultively pressed while holding those hotkeys and do some action if you find the right combination or just clear the array if the next key doesn't come along with any modifier.

Somehing like:

```
private void button1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e) 
{

   if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift) 
   {
       AddtoShiftArray(e.keyCode);
       clearAllOtherBuffers(); //ignore and listen for hotkey again

       if(seeIFWithWhatIHaveHereICanDoStuff()){
           doMyStuff();
           clearShiftBuffer();
       }
   }
   //Same for ctrl
   //Same for alt

}
```

hope this helps! :D